# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isListening')

Tags: rest, binance-chain

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3("https://bsc.getblock.io/f95df379-c65d-4cc2-90ea-9ca85a3a2350/testnet/");

const address = '0x2F2B30C2149aE38983Edccd307740ddaC9858E68'; // replace with the address you want to check

web3.eth.getBalance(address).then(balance => {
  console.log(`Address ${address} has a balance of ${web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether')} BNB`);
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

I am Using this code to getBalance of binance but I am getting error .....
console.log(`Address ${address} has a balance of ${web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether')} BNB`);
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromWei')

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue, you can try updating your Web3.js version to the latest one by running the following command in your project directory:

Try this: npm install web3@latest